# Qt application is permanently stuck at MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx. What does it mean?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I'm debugging someone else's program, which happens to get stuck once in a while. I was able to reproduce one of the *stuck moments*. When I get the program to stuck and pause it, I see this code, which is part of Qt framework:

```
    // still nothing - wait for message or signalled objects
    canWait = (!retVal
               && !d->interrupt
               && (flags & QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents));
    if (canWait) {
        DWORD nCount = d->winEventNotifierList.count();
        Q_ASSERT(nCount < MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS - 1);
        for (int i=0; i<(int)nCount; i++)
            pHandles[i] = d->winEventNotifierList.at(i)->handle();

        emit aboutToBlock();
        >BREAKHERE> waitRet = MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(nCount, pHandles, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT, MWMO_ALERTABLE | MWMO_INPUTAVAILABLE);
        emit awake();
        if (waitRet - WAIT_OBJECT_0 < nCount) {
            d->activateEventNotifier(d->winEventNotifierList.at(waitRet - WAIT_OBJECT_0));
            retVal = true;
        }
    }
```

The code is stuck at `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`. I don't think this is a problem in Qt framework or Winapi (`MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` is winapi function). I think the application causes this situation.

Because I have no experience with this function, or Qt, I just want to ask: What are possible causes of being stuck at `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`? What does that method do (I read MSDN, didn't help)?

Comment: It waits until one or more objects in pHandles array "are in the signaled state, an I/O completion routine or asynchronous procedure call (APC) is queued to the thread". Check, what are these objects doing.

Comment: What do you mean by application being "stuck"? Which thread is "stuck"? All that you've shown is that the thread in question waits for Windows and/or other threads to notify it of new events.

Comment: @KubaOber Here you go, *you've shown is that the thread in question waits for Windows and/or other threads to notify it of new events*, that's practically answer to my question. I'm not asking anyone to fix it for me. I just need a little hint what are possible reasons for execution to be stuck here. From what you say it sounds like some lock between threads.

Comment: You're reading it the wrong way, see my answer. Your application isn't "stuck", it's **doing the right thing!** *Please indicate what you mean by the application being stuck.* Most likely you're seeing a problem where there isn't one.

Comment: Pretty much every Windows application spends the majority of its lifetime in one of the message retrieval functions (`GetMessage`, `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`, etc.). This is normal for an event-based system. There's no need to burn clock cycles, when nothing has happened, and the kernel puts those threads to sleep, until an interesting event occurred. To debug a deadlock, use [WinDbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063.aspx), or have a look at [Wait Chain Traversal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681622.aspx).

Comment: And todays lesson is that sometimes it's worth to post a question even when you know people will downvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any idle Windows application will be "stuck" in this or a similar API call. **It's not an indication of any error, it's the correct behavior!** The `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` call will return as soon as there are new event notifications available for the application, e.g. when you try to interact with it iff the thread is the GUI thread.

Comment: Well then the application is stuck somewhere else. GUI thread is stuck for sure. But this is what I needed to know to move on with the debugging.